# Python 2.5 error-Graph display

Tags: python, networkx

Could someone please look at the error below and advice me if it could be fixed or what it means. I am new Python and trying to make the software work developed by someone else. It should generate an image file at the end but it doesn't. Thanks.[Python2.5, Windows]

[image: click to see the error]

```
#print "solution is " , solution
    G=XDiGraph()
    # 1. edging r_in to web services
    r_in = Set(goalService.inputList)
    #print "Ri is :", r_in
    r_out = Set(goalService.outputList)
    #print "Ro is :", r_out

    for ws in solution:
        if Set(self.webServiceList[ws].inputList).issubset(r_in):
            G.add_edge('Ri', ws, 1)
            #print "Ri fully matches ", ws
        elif len (Set(self.webServiceList[ws].inputList).intersection(r_in)) !=0 :
            G.add_edge('Ri', ws, 0)
            #print "Ri partially matches ", ws

    if r_out.issubset(r_in):
        G.add_edge('Ri', 'Ro', 1)
        #print "Ri fully matches Ro"
    elif len (r_out.intersection(r_in)) !=0 :
        G.add_edge('Ri', 'Ro', 0)
        #print "Ri partially matches Ro"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1: update the code you're running to use weighted `DiGraph`s rather than `XDiGraph`s.

Option 2: install an older version of networkx.  `XDiGraph` was removed after networkx version 0.37.